# Sending mail via php script using wamp server

Tags: php, email, wamp, mail-server

I am using WAMP server 2.4. I want to send a mail to my gmail account. The code I used for the  same is given below. I read some forums and they suggested me to make changes in php.ini file.But it is not a permanent solution.Also some suggested that mail() does not work for gmail ? Is there some solution to this?

```
       <?php
      //Checking if entries are ok 
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {

         if(isset($_POST['username']))
         $id = $_POST['username'];

         else 
         echo "Cannot be blank";

         //ensuring mail goes to registered user
         $query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = '$id' ";
         $result= mysql_query($query,$con);


         if (!($result) )
         {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
         }

         else
         {

              $values = mysql_fetch_array($result);
         }

       // Sending mail...
         if(mysql_num_rows($result)== 1)
         {
          if(isset($_POST['email']))
          $to= $_POST['email'];
              else
              echo "invalid email";
              $msg = 'Name :' .$values['name'] ."\n"
                    .'Id:' .$values['id']."\n"
                    .'Email:' .$values['email']."\n"
          ."Your password is:" . $values[password];

            mail($to,"Forget your Password",$msg);
            header('location: sent_mail.php');


    }
        else 
        echo "Verify your username again";
}
    else{
    echo "sending failed";
    header('location: forget_password.php');
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [PHPMimeMail](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmimemail/) to send mail from your localhost to gmail. To send email to gmail, you should send authenticated mail like SMTP mail. You should configure your mail username,password, and your mail host in your mail configurtion.

sample PHPmailer script for Gmail :

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "mail@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "12345";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Balaji K');

$mail->AddReplyTo("mail2@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->Body($body);
$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Folks. After many hours of trying I found that: You don't need additional tools like mailservers or pear additions. These only provide additional potential security leaks that you have no control or insight over. To get mail function to work on localhost, all you need to do is change the php.ini file. I just checked my outlook account settings and copied those to the php.ini file. So SMTP server, port, username and password.

Now, You may think it does not work but You should know that many mail clients reject emails if the From field has a different domain than the actual domain an email is received from. So if the php.ini file contains for example smtp.ziggo.nl Be sure that the header contains: From: info@ziggo.nl

So for making universal code on both localhost and remote host, I check for the existence of a file that I only have locally (e.g. z_local) and set the headers accordingly. If the local file does not exist I must be on the remote ISP and choose the header "From: info@remotesite.com"